# Direct access to clients behind NAT

Tags: ssh, remote-server, nat

We have a client/server application which we set a port for both server and client to listen to and then enter a list of clients as IP (Host)/Port pair in the server's admin panel for monitoring clients.

Then the server connects to clients and asks them to send some information and so on.

It works fine in the local network but the problem is running a server on the Internet and accessing clients behind a NAT/Firewall.

We cannot make them change their routers' configuration or their routers may not have the port forwarding feature. We can only run the client application on their computers.

We don't have access to client routers. Clients are individual users who use some random ISP and may have dynamic IP addresses.

Which solutions exist for solving this problem? Writing custom software or using ssh tunnelling...?

Comment: VPNs are the classic solution

Comment: Servers connecting to clients is not a normal pattern. Clients "phoning home" is the normal pattern. This design pattern solves problems like this (among others). Else your "Server" is not a server; *it* is the client.

Comment: Because we want clients have their Internet access and not tunneling whole system VPN is not a solution (or it's last solution)

Comment: Extra details added

Comment: Thank you. But now there's a massive "WTF??". By asking to reach out to the clients, one assumes that they are corporate clients with a networking team to design and manage a 3rd party reaching into the network. Not that you want to penetrate a home user's network and computer. I now ***emphatically*** repeat my suggestion above: you are using the wrong design pattern!! You do not want the responsibility for what you are asking to do. There isn't enough liability insurance in the world to cover you.

Comment: I don't see an information **security** question here. This question is solely asking about network **connectivity** and is thus off-topic. Apart from that there are concepts where the internal service connects to some cloud based broker and meets the client there - for example ngrok, Cloudflare Access, ZScaler Private Access etc.

Comment: @user3067948 then don't tunnel all of their traffic through VPN, just what is needed

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to setup [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on LAN router.

From the Wikipedia page linked above:

> This technique is most commonly used to make services on a host
> residing on a protected or masqueraded (internal) network available to
> hosts on the opposite side of the gateway (external network), by
> remapping the destination IP address and port number of the
> communication to an internal host.

Comment: Both server and clients are on the Internet (server has a static IP). I don't think this is a solution for this scenario.

Comment: If the client is behind a NAT router, and the client is to accept incoming connections (which in itself is counter-intuitive), then the incoming connections from the WAN side of the router must be forwarded to the LAN side of the router (where the 'client' is).  This is what port-forwarding is for.  Another option is for the client to setup an SSH tunnel to the server in advance, then the server can connect to a service running on the client through a reverse ssh tunnel.  See https://www.howtogeek.com/428413/what-is-reverse-ssh-tunneling-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: Clients are on the internet? I thought they were behind a NAT?

Comment: @mti2935 the details have radically changed. Port forwarding is not an option.

Comment: +1 down the line for everything that @schroeder said.  Your clients should be like ET and phone home.  Given that your clients have dynamic IP's, are they are not tech-savvy enough to setup a port-forward, VPN, or SSH tunnel - I don't think there is any other viable solution.  IOW, let the client be a client.